# Extract embedded file which is not listed in NAMES

Tags: java, pdfbox

I'm trying to extract an embedded file from [a PDF](http://lhorn.de/~lutz/1_ZUGFeRD_Beispielrechnug.pdf) that is located here:

```
Catalog / AF[0] / EF / F
```

- `AF` is an array
- the first entry is a File Specification Dictionary
- `EF` is a Dictionary
- `F` is supposed to be an Embedded File Stream

Using PDFBox I can get this far:

```
PDFParser parser = new PDFParser(is);
parser.parse();
PDDocument document = parser.getPDDocument();
PDDocumentCatalog catalog = document.getDocumentCatalog();
PDDocumentNameDictionary namesDictionary = new PDDocumentNameDictionary(catalog);
PDEmbeddedFilesNameTreeNode embeddedFiles = namesDictionary.getEmbeddedFiles();
List<PDNameTreeNode> kids = embeddedFiles.getKids();
PDEmbeddedFilesNameTreeNode node = (PDEmbeddedFilesNameTreeNode) kids.get(0);
COSDictionary cosDictionary = node.getCOSDictionary();
COSArray a = (COSArray) cosDictionary.getDictionaryObject(COSName.NAMES);
COSDictionary d = (COSDictionary) a.getObject(1);
COSDictionary ef = (COSDictionary) d.getDictionaryObject(COSName.EF);
COSDictionary f = (COSDictionary) ef.getDictionaryObject(COSName.F);
System.out.println(f);
```

Output (formatted for better readability):

```
COSDictionary{(COSName{Length}:COSInt{1433})
              (COSName{Filter}:COSName{FlateDecode})
              (COSName{Type}:COSName{EmbeddedFile})
              (COSName{Subtype}:COSName{text/xml})
              (COSName{Params}:COSDictionary{
                (COSName{Size}:COSInt{12030})
                (COSName{ModDate}:COSString{D:20130628111510+02'00'})
               }
              )
             }
```

That is what I expect so far. But where are the bytes of this embedded XML file? How can I access them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a much simpler way. Since the embedded file is under `KIDS`, not `NAMES`, which would be correct, this works:

```
List<PDNameTreeNode> kids = embeddedFiles.getKids();
if (kids != null) {
  for (PDNameTreeNode kid : embeddedFiles.getKids()) {
    PDComplexFileSpecification spec =
      (PDComplexFileSpecification) kid.getValue(ZUGFERD_XML_FILENAME);
    PDEmbeddedFile file = spec.getEmbeddedFile();
    return file.getByteArray();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should have a look at the [ExtractEmbeddedFiles](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/pdmodel/ExtractEmbeddedFiles.java?view=markup) example provided by PDFBox. It describes how to extract all kind of embedded files.

Comment: This example relies on `namesDictionary.getEmbeddedFiles()` to return the names. That's what I do, too :)

Comment: @Lehmi Please answer only if you are fairly sure to be able to contribute something and avoid phrases like "maybe you should do xy..." in answers.